# How to Keep Highlighted ListView Item and Its Status in the Contextual Action Bar during Device Orientation Change

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview implemented with its choice mode set to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`. Here is some of the code:

```
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            private int check = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.clearSelection();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                check = 0;

                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, arg1);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode arg0,
                    MenuItem arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ((PinPad.mMediaPlayer != null)
                        && (!PinPad.mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())) {
                    switch (arg1.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.item_delete:

                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(
                                R.layout.delete_confirmation, null);
                        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                MainListActivity.this);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogLayout);

                        final AlertDialog confirmationDialog = alertDialogBuilder
                                .create();
                        confirmationDialog.show();

                        Button buttonNo = (Button) dialogLayout
                                .findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);
                        Button buttonYes = (Button) dialogLayout
                                .findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);

                        buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                weGotTheTime.clear();
                                weGotTheType.clear();
                                weGotTheDays.clear();
                                weGotTheRings.clear();

                                weGotTheIDs.clear();

                                confirmationDialog.dismiss();
                                adapter.clearSelection();
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                refreshListView();
                                check = 0;
                                arg0.finish();
                            }
                        });

                        buttonYes
                                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        databaseData.open();
                                        databaseData.deleteEntries(
                                                weGotTheTime, weGotTheType,
                                                weGotTheDays);
                                        databaseData.close();

                                        new AlarmTask(MainListActivity.this,
                                                weGotTheIDs, weGotTheDays,
                                                weGotTheRings, weGotTheType,
                                                weGotTheTime).cancelAl();

                                        weGotTheTime.clear();
                                        weGotTheType.clear();
                                        weGotTheDays.clear();
                                        weGotTheRings.clear();

                                        weGotTheIDs.clear();

                                        confirmationDialog.dismiss();
                                        adapter.clearSelection();
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        refreshListView();
                                        check = 0;
                                        arg0.finish();
                                    }
                                });
                        break;
                    }

                    return true;
                } else if (PinPad.mMediaPlayer == null) {
                    switch (arg1.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.item_delete:

                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(
                                R.layout.delete_confirmation, null);
                        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                MainListActivity.this);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogLayout);

                        final AlertDialog confirmationDialog = alertDialogBuilder
                                .create();
                        confirmationDialog.show();

                        Button buttonNo = (Button) dialogLayout
                                .findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);
                        Button buttonYes = (Button) dialogLayout
                                .findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);

                        buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                weGotTheTime.clear();
                                weGotTheType.clear();
                                weGotTheDays.clear();
                                weGotTheRings.clear();

                                weGotTheIDs.clear();

                                confirmationDialog.dismiss();
                                adapter.clearSelection();
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                refreshListView();
                                check = 0;
                                arg0.finish();
                            }
                        });

                        buttonYes
                                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        databaseData.open();
                                        databaseData.deleteEntries(
                                                weGotTheTime, weGotTheType,
                                                weGotTheDays);
                                        databaseData.close();

                                        new AlarmTask(MainListActivity.this,
                                                weGotTheIDs, weGotTheDays,
                                                weGotTheRings, weGotTheType,
                                                weGotTheTime).cancelAl();

                                        weGotTheTime.clear();
                                        weGotTheType.clear();
                                        weGotTheDays.clear();
                                        weGotTheRings.clear();

                                        weGotTheIDs.clear();

                                        confirmationDialog.dismiss();
                                        adapter.clearSelection();
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        refreshListView();
                                        check = 0;
                                        arg0.finish();
                                    }
                                });
                        break;
                    }

                    return true;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Cannot delete alarm(s). Make sure no alarm is currently ringing.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    adapter.clearSelection();
                    check = 0;
                    arg0.finish();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                    int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                td = results.get(position).getDays();

                if (checked) {

                    check++;
                    adapter.setNewSelection(position, checked);
                    weGotTheTime.add(results.get(position).getTime());
                    weGotTheType.add(results.get(position).getType());
                    weGotTheDays.add(results.get(position).getDays());
                    weGotTheIDs.add(results.get(position).getID());
                    weGotTheRings.add(results.get(position).getTitle());
                } else {
                    check--;
                    adapter.removeSelection(position);
                    weGotTheTime.remove(results.get(position).getTime());
                    weGotTheType.remove(results.get(position).getType());
                    weGotTheDays.remove(results.get(position).getDays());
                    weGotTheIDs.remove(results.get(position).getID());
                    weGotTheRings.remove(results.get(position).getTitle());
                }

                mode.setTitle(check + " selected");
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                listView.setItemChecked(arg2, !adapter.isPositionChecked(arg2));
                vibrator.vibrate(50);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

This works great, long clicking a listview item highlights it and it works fine. However, once I change the device orientation from portrait to landscape and vice versa, the highlighting is gone and the Contextual Action Bar is still showing however it doesn't show anything is selected. Any help? I've tried making selectors and drawables and manually doing it that way and still no luck. I've spent weeks on this one issue and I'm wondering if somebody out there knows how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: your acivity must be recreated, have you tried to keep information using onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() ?

Comment: I have yes, and it only saved the number of selections made. What's weird is that when I call, `listView.setItemChecked(position, true);` it's as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can using this helps:

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

For more info on complete implementation  refer this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: I've tried using this method but unfortunately it didn't work.